# Custom File type with UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios

I cannot get the `UIActivityViewController` to attach a custom file type created with `UIDocument`.  Can anyone help?

The email has no attachment at all, even though the file URL is valid, and points to a file with a `.wki` extension (my custom extension), created via a subclass of `UIDocument`.

Code for sending email:

```
    NSURL *url = self.entrySelected.fileURL;

    NSArray *activityItems = @[url];

    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Info-plist setting for Document Types and Exported UTI's are:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array/>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>MyApp Doc</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.stephencox.myApp.doc</string>
        </array>
        <key>LSTypeIsPackage</key>
        <string>YES</string>
    </dict>
</array>


<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.apple.package</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>MyApp Doc</string>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.stephencox.myApp.doc</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <array>
                <string>wki</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing, and what is weird is it was working for a while and then something stopped it from working but I don't know what.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am having the same problem with my own file extension ".wpt". The strange thing is that if I change the extension of the filename to something else, then it does work. But of course that is not an option.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, in my case trying to attach a ".momd" versioned managed object model package. I wonder if the problem is iOS can't fully handle file packages? According to Apple's Documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html) the "LSTypeIsPackage" key is applicable for OS X only.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with my own file type. After a lot of experimentation, I found a solution for it, hope it also works for you.

You **must** specify a MIME type for the file, for example:

```
...
    <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
    <dict>
        <key>public.filename-extension</key>
        <string>wki</string>
        <key>public.mime-type</key>
        <string>application/x-wki</string>
    </dict>
...
```

Comment: I have tried your solution, but am still unable to make it work.

I have added a key for public.mime-type, and tried everything I can think of in the string value. I have tried typing in literally what you suggested, i.e., ‘application/x-wki’, and every other option I can think of (e.g., MyApp/x-wki, MyApp/wki, application/wki, com.stephencox.myApp/wki, package/wki, com.apple.package/wki, etc etc), but have not found anything that works.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually solved my problem by setting up another document type and UTExportedTypeDeclaration.

I left the first alone (assuming the UIDocument management needed it), and set up another doc type for a zipped file, where the UTTypeConformsTo key was set to “public.data”, and an additional key was added for public.mime-type (set to “applications/myappname”).  I sent the zipped file to a temporary directory, and had the UIActivityViewController pick up the file from this URL.

Hope this helps someone else!